# How do you put environmental variables in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, connection-string, appsettings

I am currently [Following these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-sms-and-email-two-factor-authentication), and I am wanting to call the clear text string from Azure's Application Settings for Web Apps. I am under the impression that environmental variables are [used for non-config files](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/). However, I am wanting to use the same methodology for web.config files.

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="/config/ConnectionStrings.config">
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('SQLAZURECONNSTR_DefaultConnection')" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings file="config\AppSettingsSecret.config">
    <!-- Code Removed for Conciseness-->
    <add key="mailAccount" value="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('APPSETTING_mailAccount')" />
    <add key="mailPassword" value="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('APPSETTING_mailPassword')" />
    <!-- Twilio-->
    <add key="TwilioSid" value="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('APPSETTING_TwilioSid')" />
    <add key="TwilioToken" value="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('APPSETTING_TwilioToken')" />
    <add key="TwilioFromPhone" value="@Environment.GetEnvironmentalVariable('APPSETTING_TwilioFromPhone')" />
  </appSettings>
```

Note: I included the configSource="/example/" for local testing.

Comment: Config files don't allow for code like that. You'd have to use the `%APPSETTING_something%` syntax and expand it out when reading the value. On a side-note, have you seen web.config transforms? That's the accepted method of setting values for different environments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### For Applications, including Web Applications, On Windows:

The values in `<appSettings>` are just strings. If you want environmental variables to be expanded your application will need to do that itself.

A common way of doing this is to use the `cmd` syntax `%variable%` and then using [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to expand them.

#### On Azure:

The rules are different (see links in the question): but the values appear to be in environment variables so, in the config file:

```
<add key='SomeSetting' value='%APPSETTING_some_key%'/>
```

and then to retrieve:

```
var someSetting = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                     ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("SomeSetting"))
```

may well work.

Comment: Wouldn't it be CloudConfigurationManager.AppSetting?