# How does one set JVM command line options when running a Java application on Azure Cloud Services?

Tags: java, azure, azure-cloud-services

I've created a hello world java application on Azure Cloud Services following this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-creating-a-hello-world-application/
For a more advanced application, I need to set the JVM command line options. Where can I set these? In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, these are set in Configuration > Software Configuration, but I don't see an equivalent on the Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS='-DyourOption= -Danotheroption='

If it is a linux then it would be like

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS='-DyourOption= -Danotheroption='
```

EDIT: related to [How and where to define an environment variable on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure)

Answer (score 0):

@DylanColaco, the solution is that you can define the JVM options as environment variables in the `startup.cmd` file of Role instance or in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file via the Eclipse as below.

[image]

As reference, you can refer to the tutorial [`How to configure and run startup tasks for a cloud service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/) to know how to set up.