# Azure Web API set Environment Variables

Tags: azure, environment-variables, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to authenticate to Firebase Firestore on a C# WebAPi 2 hosted in Azure.
According to the [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html#authentication), it's as easy as:

> Otherwise, the simplest way of authenticating your API calls is to
>   download a service account JSON file then set the
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to refer to it.
>   The credentials will automatically be used to authenticate. See the
>   Getting Started With Authentication guide for more details.

This works locally on my machine but I can't seem to find a way how to set this environment variable in a Azure WebApp?

Comment: You can set an App Setting. Those become environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

As Junnas mentioned you can set the App settings, which will act as environment variables.

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/00/00/01/03/74/metablogapi/8255.image_thumb_5CE44ECE.png))</sub>

In Asp.Net 5 there is a build in

```
Configuration = new Configuration()
             .AddJsonFile("config.json")
             .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

Read this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/stuartleeks/azure-api-apps-configuration-with-environment-variables) and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure)

You can find all the predefined environment variables at below link,

`https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml`

Comment: Thanks, I came across those as well but they are asp.net 5, our backend is running v2.2 with .NET 4.6.1

The blog you mentioned uses a helper for older Web API versions (which I am using). It's only for reading variables though.

I see that System.Environment has Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NAME","VALUE")

Where value could be the path to the service account JSON file but how do I upload the json file and what path would it be?

Comment: still haven't figured out how to do it but found a work around for my problem.
1: Store the JSON file in App_Data folder. 2: create web.config overrides for each environment / developer if the files are different. 3: Get the file from App_Data.                            

var fullPathToGoogleServicesJson = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($@"~/App_Data/{CoreSettings.FirebaseProjectGoogleServicesJsonFileName}");

pass the file to FirestoreClient