# Azure function app reading from App Settings not working

Tags: azure, azure-app-configuration

I have an Azure Function App that I am attempting to secure with OKTA.
In the root of my function app I have an auth.json file and I am replacing the Client Id etc with settings in my App Settings..except they arent replacing. It is keeping the literal values.
[image]

I am wanting to reference the item "MYSECRET".

This is the content of my auth.json that lives in the root of the Function APP:
[image]

For Line 15 I have attempted both:

- "%MYSECRET%"
- "MYSECRET"

But I am getting the literal value "MYSECRET" rather than the value behind it, "1234". Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the App Service Settings won't affect your auth.json file. If that's what you want, you should use Azure Devops to perform the transformations for you.

As another option, just use regular Environments Variable.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34622196/1384539