# Permanently set environment variable in Azure Pipeline

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines

While [all sites about environment variables on Azure Pipelines seem to talk about setting variables before pipeline start,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure) I want to set (change) the variable `PATH` in one step and use it in a later step.
But using

```
      steps:
       - script: source ./export_variables.sh
         displayName: "export variables"
       - script: $PATH 
         displayName: "verify"
         condition: succeeded()
```

where `./export_variables.sh` contains something like

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=abc/def/bin:$PATH
```

does not fulfill the task: In the verify step PATH does not contain `abc/def/bin`.

What has to be changed so that upates of $PATH become permanent on the machine?

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same issue. It was solved with the following lines in the YAML

```
steps:
      - bash: |
          export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.local/bin"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=PATH;]${PATH}"
```

Which gives me the variable set over the entire stage. Note that this will overwrite the PATH so use with care :)