# Is there a way to read appsettings as a environment variable for .net 6 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Web API application and I have define one key in "appsettings.json" file in a below way,

```
{
 "UID": "myUid"
}
```

Now I want to read the "UID" key like as environment variable like,

```
 var x = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UID");
```

It's give me "null" result. What fix is required here?

I know I can put the key in `launsettings.json` and it will work, but I want to put only in appsettings.

Comment: Have you actually set the environment variable in the machine where your app is running?

Comment: good catch. I am running over Azure Web Service :(

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608769/how-and-where-to-define-an-environment-variable-on-azure

Comment: Yes. This help, but to run locally I need to put the configuration in launsettings, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core allows hierarchical set up for setting sources. By [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#default-application-configuration-sources) `WebApplicationBuilder` provides configuration for the app in the following order, from highest to lowest priority:

> - Command-line arguments using the Command-line configuration provider.
> - Non-prefixed environment variables using the Non-prefixed environment variables configuration provider.
> - User secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.
> - `appsettings.{Environment}.json` using the JSON configuration provider. For example, `appsettings.Production.json` and `appsettings.Development.json`.
> - `appsettings.json` using the JSON configuration provider.
> - A fallback to the host configuration ([read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#host))

For development environments you can use [`launchSettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) to set up environment variables. So for local development environment you can use it or just provide required config via `appsettings.Development.json` or set them via [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-environment-on-the-command-line) parameters.

Personally I tend to exclude `launchSettings.json` from version control monitoring and use it for user specific environment settings (i.e. settings which are highly likely to differ for different developers) and use `appsettings.Development.json` for everything else.

Comment: For VS Code users, I would like to add to this marvelous answer that environment variables are set in the `launch.json` file in the `.vscode` folder.