# Is it possible to reference environmental variables within a .Net projects web.config settings?

Tags: .net, plugins, web-config, environment-variables, cas

I'm setting up a development template for `.Net` projects. With that I'm using [dot-net-cas-client](https://github.com/apereo/dotnet-cas-client) for authentication backed by ADFS. The issue is, at times our CAS developer changes/migrates the service to new URLs.

Thus, if a plethora of projects were live and an update to the CAS URL has changed. I wouldn't want to manually update CAS URL locations for every live projects' `web.config file` (I did consider creating a Powershell script that would read through all of the server directories searching for the `web.config` files and then read through by line and capture the CAS URL strings to replace, but that seems outdated and could be problematic).

I was hoping to use environmental variables at the system or machine level, that way the `web.config` files could reference one location and obtain the current URL there. Thus only one location would need to be updated when/if a change occurred.

I see that I can add a key to get environment variables' values and use it within the projects code, but I didn't find anything about then using that key or reference directly within the `web.config` file.

I've attempted to create and reference a key, reference the environment variable directly `%environmentVariableName%`, but wasn't sure on if it was possible within the `web.config`.

I attempted to reference the variable `%system.variable%` directly but didn't obtain the environmental variable value.

`dot-net-cas-client` settings:

```
<casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl="https://example.com/cas/login"....
```

Replaced by something like:

```
<casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl="%environmentVariableName%"....
```

OR

```
<casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl=%environmentVariableName%....
```

OR

```
<casClientConfig casServerLoginUrl=Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("environmentVariableName"))....
```

The above all threw errors (missing quotes) or the request sent me to `...%environmentVariableName%...` rather then `...example.com/cas/login...`

I understand you can add a KEY which I have also tried:

```
<add key='SomeSetting' value='%environmentVariableName%'/>
```

But didn't see anything about referencing that KEY directly in the settings of the `web.config` file.

`dot-net-cas-client` "casServerLoginUrl" and other attributes expect a string encapsulated by quotes. Or directed me to my URL, but with `%environmentVariableName%` instead of the value stored in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I'm looking to do something similar also with AWS posting to Environment variables. I haven't found a silver bullet yet, but here's what I've found.

If you want to use the way you're describing above, the variables do not expand automatically  (although maybe in AZURE/.NETcore they do???) :
[How do you put environmental variables in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416302/how-do-you-put-environmental-variables-in-web-config)
You have to expand it yourself in all usages - (maybe a wrapper func would be nice)
 you can also use **Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(myvar)**

```
var someSetting = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("SomeSetting"))
```

OR

a powershell way (as you mentioned earlier, it also seems hacky to me, but may be the best solution)
https://anthonychu.ca/post/overriding-web-config-settings-environment-variables-containerized-aspnet-apps/

Comment: Hi,

Sorry, this will not work. I can create a Key pointing to the string in the Environment Variables, but can't create or use variables within the web.config file.

So while I can create describe a variable, I can't use it later within the web.config like:

var setting = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSetting("SomeSetting"));

<forms name=".DotNetCasClientAuth" loginUrl=setting.....